# Concrete5 Displaying Database Values

Tags: php, mysql, concrete5

I'm using Concrete5 and I want to display a page version and last modified date on the page. I have managed to get it to display the version using:

```
<?php echo t('Version %s', $c->getVersionID())?>
```

This is where I get confused, I believe that this is coming from the table *collectionversions* and the column *cvID*. Am I right to assume this?

I then tried entering:

```
<?php echo t('Version %s', $c->getVersionDateCreated())?>
```

assuming again that it's looking at the table *collectionversions* and the column *DateCreated*. But it doesn't work.

My question therefore is: How do you get Concrete5 to display data from a certain table and column? Also, is my code pointing to a table different than the one I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

Actually because you are using the variable $c which represents the current page, what you are using when doing $c->getVersionID() is using a function from the Page model. That model itself extends the Collection model.

Actually, in Concrete5 legacy it is in the Page model. In 5.7  it is in the collection model.

The database table here is not important as you have function already written to get the data you want.

Knowing this, you have access to 3 functions:

To get the date the current version was made public:

```
$c->getCollectionDatePublic();
```

To get the date of last modification - which is not necessarily the same as the previous one:

```
$c->getCollectionDateLastModified();
```

To get the date the page was created, not just the last version:

```
$c->getCollectionDateAdded();
```

If you want to look at the files, in Concrete5 legacy:
concrete\core\models\page.php and concrete\core\models\collection.php

In concrete5 5.7.x: If you want to look at the files, in Concrete5 legacy:
concrete\src\Page\Page.php and concrete\src\Page\Collection\Collection.php